# UltiSnip: Insert matched regex

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have a ultisnip that looks like this:

```
snippet "[A-Z]+-[0-9]+" "Jira Link" r
[`!p snip.rv = match.group(0)`](https://ellation.atlassian.net/browse/`!p snip.rv = match.group(0)`)
endsnippet
```

This works fine. But I was hoping there might be a way to do this *without* duplicating the two python blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Instead of interleaving actual text with Python code, build the whole string with Python:

```
snippet "[A-Z]+-[0-9]+" "Jira Link" r
`!p identifier = match.group(0)
snip.rv = "".join([
    "[", identifier, "]"
    "(https://ellation.atlassian.net/browse/", identifier, ")"])`
endsnippet
```